# How to change a div when user click on Twitter Follow button @anywhere

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I am looking to change a DIV when I know a user is following me.
I cant get the code to fire the alerts.
The follow button does show up, but after i click and follow, nothing happens.

```
twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
    T("#followplaceholder").followButton('twitterapi');
    function follow(){
        T.currentUser.isFollowing('twitterapi'), function(e){
            if (e == true){
                alert("following");
            } else {
                 alert("not following");
            }
        }; 
    }                                                             
});
```

Any help would be great!

---

Here is the code i am trying to use now.  Where do i call the function to get it fired? Or should i just take the function part out?

```
twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
    T("#followplaceholder").followButton('twitterapi');
    function follow(){
        T.currentUser.isFollowing('twitterapi'), function(e){
            if (e == true){
                alert("following");
            } else {
                 alert("not following");
            }
        }; 
    }                                                             
});
```

Comment: Is the ('tweetapi']?>', part correct?

Comment: Looks like some extraneous code to me. Maybe poorly-removed PHP?

Comment: yeah. my bad i took that out..

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra **)** after 'twitterapi'

try this:

```
function follow(){
    T.currentUser.isFollowing('twitterapi', function(e){
        if (e == true){
            alert("following");
        } else {
            alert("not following");
        }
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the follow funcion even triggered? It's just standing there doing nothing?
And like the others sad there is a piece of PHP inthere..., it has to be a `)` i think.

Also watch your console log for errors.

Comment: How would i call the function?  I am not much of a javascript guy.

Comment: It should be triggered when you click the button, so add an `onclick` event to the button? It would be nice when you post the code of your hole page so we can see the button's html etc.

Answer (score 0):

`T.currentUser.isFollowing('tweetapi']?>', function(e){`

A straight-forward bug.  `?>` is php code, so you might want to use `)` instead of `]?>`

Comment: Yeah actually that was a mistake on my part.  I was having tweetapi filled by a constant I set in my config file.   The above is now correct to reflect the right code.  I still never did get it working though